# codeigniter with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter

I am planning a new website with codeigniter using wordpress.
this site will contain creating online albums, selling presents and gifts, and another one for selling cameras and their accessories.
is it recommended using this combination?
what are the advantages and disadvantage of this?
is there a better solution for building with framework and cms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why did you decided to use a working cms and a php framework together? Just using one of both is enough. The advantage you will have with wordpress is the fact that there are many plugins that are easily to use. For Codeigniter you will have to do all of the codings for yourself but you can build your website like you want it to be!

Comment: Why is that weird? I can use the power of wordpress as a backend, and the power of codeigniter as the front.. is't that a good reason?

Comment: Wordpress has a good frontend aswell. But if you really want to use both you can. The only you should worry about is when wordpress gets a major update.

Comment: but, in your opinion, what is better to use?

Comment: I would just stick to Wordpress or to CodeIgniter and dont use both for a single website. If you dont have a lot of programming knowledge stay with Wordpress. If you know how to code an entire website use Codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

Personally (Having experience of both) It all depends on what your objectives are. Are you wanting to quickly and easily pull the project together, or do you have unlimited time and want everything to be feature rich and customized to your exact specification? CodeIgniter will allow you to build each aspect exactly as you want, where as WordPress (through the use of plugins) will allow you to get the end result you want without quiet as much customization.
However, that being said there is nothing saying you can't use CodeIgniter and direct traffic to the WordPress part for certain aspects, all down to your personal preference.